# what is the type of this cluase?

Tags: tense, clauses

what part of the sentence is *embrace*?

> She saw them embrace on the station platform.

I expected it to be *embracing*.

Comment: Why would you expect the verb to be "embracing"?

Comment: @BillJ I guess it is originally like this: She saw them that were embracing on the station platform.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *She saw them embracing*.
>
> [2] *She saw them embrace*.

Either verb-form is possible.

The gerund-participial in [1] has a progressive meaning: strictly speaking, in [2] she saw the whole event of their embracing, in [1] a segment of it.

In reality, though, there is little real semantic difference between the two, so  it's a free choice.